# customization on sql datetime format how?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to convert `date time` to `nvarchar` on sql server like `2011 Oct 24`
 but I'm not able to convert into this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

There's no [format that matches exactly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).  You can use `substring` to assemble the format manually:

```
select  substring(convert(varchar(20),getdate(),106),8,4) + ' ' +
        substring(convert(varchar(20),getdate(),106),4,3) + ' ' +
        substring(convert(varchar(20),getdate(),106),1,3)
```

N.B. Doing formatting in SQL is much harder than client-side, in C# or Java or Ruby.

Comment: +1 : Strongly agree to format data in the client if at all possible.

Comment: You don't need to use subsrting for this. you can get all parts seperately like : SELECT DATENAME(YYYY,GETDATE()) + ' ' + CAST(DATENAME(MM,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' ' + DATENAME(DD,GETDATE())

Answer (score 2):

For, exact format you required, you need to get all parts(day,month and year) of date seperately like :

```
SELECT DATENAME(YYYY,GETDATE()) + ' ' + CAST(DATENAME(MM,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' ' + DATENAME(DD,GETDATE())
```

You can also user convert function for other formats like :

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),106)
```

Comment: Prints `24 Oct 2011` instead of `2011 Oct 24`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(10), getdate(), 102)
```

You can find all of the conversion codes here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH d (d) AS (SELECT GETDATE())
SELECT DATENAME(YEAR, d) + ' ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(6), d, 109)
FROM d
```

Output:

```
-------------------------------------
2011 Oct 24
```