# Better way to format date in nvarchar

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need date format like "2011 Oct 24" in SQL 2008 and there is no any inbuilt format in convert function to get this. I got 2 ways to achieve this. Can anybody please guide me which are best way from following 2 ways to get it in terms of execution and performance ?

```
1) select  substring(convert(varchar(20),getdate(),106),8,4) + ' ' + 
        substring(convert(varchar(20),getdate(),106),4,3) + ' ' + 
        substring(convert(varchar(20),getdate(),106),1,3) 

2) SELECT DATENAME(YYYY,GETDATE()) + ' ' + CAST(DATENAME(MM,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' ' + DATENAME(DD,GETDATE())
```

### UPDATE :

Please check below question :
[customization on sql datetime format how?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7874162/889260)
I had also given [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874162/customization-on-sql-datetime-format-how/7874182#7874182) in this question but [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874162/customization-on-sql-datetime-format-how/7874242#7874242) got more votes than my answer. So I am confused which one is best way.

Comment: Surely this is something best done at the application layer?

Comment: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: @Oded : Yes, we can do it in application layer, but I just want to know which way is better if I want it from SQL.

Answer (score 2):

What is the purpose of this?

If you are passing this to an ASP.NET Web Application, you could keep the date in its raw format and change the format at the application level:

```
String.Format(Date, "yyyy MMM dd");
```

---

However, if you need to format at SQL level, you could do the following:

```
declare @Date datetime
SET @Date = GETDATE()

SELECT CAST(YEAR(@Date) as nvarchar(4)) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(DATENAME(month, @Date), 0, 4) + ' ' + CAST(DAY(@Date) as nvarchar(2))
```

Comment: Yes, we can do it in web application, but I just want to know which way is better if I want it from SQL.

Comment: @UpendraChaudhari: it's **better** in the web client ....

Comment: @UpendraChaudhari - I've added a SQL solution to my answer

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx